# API should return only n rows at a time

Tags: mysql, rest, api, flask

I am new to API building. I have a requirement as. My API shows books details and **In case the number of books that meet the criteria exceeds 25, the API should return only 25 books at a time and support the means of retrieving the next sets of 25 books till all books are retrieved.**

Also I need a word of advice. I have 10 tables and I need to join those tables by getting some data from each of them and return the consolidated result to API call. I think 10 joins in one query will be very much memory intensive and will probably not give the best result.

I will be having some filters as well on some columns of various tables. Should I fetch rows individually for individual tables? Also in API return call some keys would be having multiple data but it is not showing with this query Below is the query which I am using:

```
SELECT b.title,a.name,b.media_type,l.code,bsub.name,bs.name,f.url FROM books_book b 
inner join books_book_authors ba on b.id=ba.book_id 
inner join books_author a on a.id=ba.author_id 
inner join books_bookshelves bss on ba.book_id=bss.book_id
inner join books_bookshelf bs on bss.bookshelf=bs.id
inner join books_book_subjects bsubs on bsubs.book_id=ba.book_id
inner join books_subject bsub on bsubs.subject_id=bsub.id
inner join books_format f on f.book_id=ba.book_id
inner join books_languages ls on ls.book_id=ba.book_id
inner join books_language l on ls.language_id=l.id
order by b.download_count desc;
```

Comment: Is there any specific reason that you are keeping data in so many different tables? attributes like author, language, subject etc can be kept with in the books table.

Comment: @arun : I got the .sql file in this format only

Comment: Have you consider building a materialized view which would keep all this info after doing the required joins and you can query the view from the API. There is an additional overhead of keeping the view though.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [limit](https://www.guru99.com/limit.html) and offset to retrieve a limited dataset

```sql
SELECT column1, column2, ...
FROM table_name
LIMIT 10 offset 5;
```

Comment: But what I dont understand is the bold part in the question. I can retrieve n number of rows but how will I be getting the data that is left. Please read the bold part in the question

Comment: That is where you use the `offset`. If you want to show 25 items on the first page that means you have `LIMIT 25 OFFSET 0` on the second page you have `LIMIT 25 OFFSET 25` and so on. Take a look at this example I made very recently for a friend. Its doing exaclty this https://github.com/bluebrown/restify-example

Comment: And what about the other part of the question? The join part

Comment: Well, you should not ask 2 questions in one. Please open a separate question for your other issue. I have answered what the title asked for. Some people would probably even downvote the question due to this.

Answer (score 0):

You can use LIMIT in SQL query to limit the page size. You also need to sort the result on the basis of book_id. In your get API you can send the book_id of the last book of the current page that you received. This book_id can then be used to return the next page from the API side.

Comment: There is requirement that data needs to be fetched in order with downloads.

Comment: And what about the join part, is that fine ? Also, as I mentioned I am not getting correct data. As for some book_id there can be multiple languages, but I am getting only one